# In how many ways can you place figures on the chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you place a white king, a black king, two white knights and a black rook on the chessboard.

As far as I know the only restriction here is that two kings cannot be on the adjacent squares.

Comment: That's the only restriction?  That's weird; the usual reason for that restriction is to ensure the kings cannot be in check.  But if so, why allow the kings to be checked by an opposing knight or rook?

Comment: Because the King being in check by a knight or a rook is still a legal board. Never in a game of chess can two kings ever be on adjacent squares.

Comment: There's another restriction: Both kings cannot be simultaneously in check. Such a position is also illegal.

Comment: In addition, I think you cannot have the black king under check by both white knights.

Comment: The black king cannot be in check from both white knights simultaneously, another restriction.

Comment: Now I see these necessary conditions. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the rules of chess and not about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

[image: problem position]

This is a comment rather than an answer, but I needed to include a picture. In addition to some of the restrictions mentioned in the comments, there are other positions that can not be achieved in legal play for less obvious reasons. In this position, the last move had to have been the black rook causing check, but there is nowhere it could have moved from.

There are surprisingly many ways to create illegal positions, so if you restrict yourself to only positions that can occur in a legal game, it can be difficult to count.

Comment: Late to the party, but this position is actually legal. The black rook came from a2 or c2, where it was a pawn at the time. Flip the board around and it becomes impossible.

Comment: @eyeballfrog You are totally right, good catch! I like how this comment actually gives further evidence for my claim, even though it is proving me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  place the white king first.  There are three kinds of squares it might be on:  a corner, an edge, or a center.  In each case, how many choices are there for the black king?  Then how many places for the other three pieces?  Note that the white knights are interchangeable.